# In how many ways can $10$ bananas be divided amongst $4$ monkeys?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a problem working with the stars and bars method. Let's give a good example:

$10$ bananas have to be divided amongst $4$ monkeys. (Giving a monkey $0$ bananas is also possible)

How many different possibilities are there?

Note: Last time I tried to solve this problem with the stars and bars method I found: $13! / 10! 3! = 286$. However there are many more possibilities.

Comment: Keep in mind that the monkeys are **different** (aka *distinguishable*), hence different arrangements also need to be accounted for.

Comment: That however does not solve my problem yet. I still cannot figure out the amount of possibilities :/

Comment: I wish to solve this particular problem @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Assuming that the bananas are indistinguishable and the monkeys are distinguishable, the correct answer *is* $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{13}3=286$. Why do you think that it isn’t?

Answer (score 0):

This case is a little bit different and has  quite a long solution as well....to start with u should make a list of all the possible cases in which the bananas can be distributed to the monkeys....I will write down a couple of cases below and calculate no. of ways for each case...The final answer will be addition of the no. of ways of each possible case...

1. 10 0 0 0
    ie 10 bananas to first monkey and
    none to the others.....
    Since the bananas are identical u
    can choose 10 bananas in only 1    way and this will remain the same for all other cases....
   Now we can distribute the bananas in 4!/3! ways =4.

   2. 8 1 1 0
      ie 8 bananas to one monkey 1 each for two monkeys and none for the last one.
      In this case....again no. of ways of choosing bananas will be 1 and no. of ways of distributing them will be equal to 4!/2!=12.

Make all such possible cases...make sure u dont repeat any case ie
 8 1 1 0 is the same as 0 1 1 8....